# How to authenticate Node.js MongoClient against Cosmos DB emulator running in VM?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm on OS X and I'm trying to use the Node.js-based `MongoClient` to connect to a CosmosDB emulator running in a Parallels VM. I'm able to get it to connect, but queries fail with an authentication error.

I looked at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#running-on-mac-or-linux) first, but I had to modify it a little to get my host machine to connect to the VM:

`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /EnableMongoDbEndpoint /Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==`

My connection string:
`mongodb://vm1:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@vm1:10255/admin?ssl=true`

After I was able to get it to connect, I couldn't figure out how to provide the equivalent of the `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` using the `MongoClient`.

The authentication error message I get:

```
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.datasets. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM] Exception: MongoError: Authentication Failed.  ConnectionId 1a87b001-e1e6-4918-9a1c-92db5719c670  ActivityId: 8c071a01-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM] Stack: MongoError: Authentication Failed.  ConnectionId 1a87b001-e1e6-4918-9a1c-92db5719c670  ActivityId: 8c071a01-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at /Users/Documents/Projects/DataStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:598:61
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at authenticateStragglers (/Users/Documents/Projects/DataStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:516:16)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/Documents/Projects/DataStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:552:5)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at emitMessageHandler (/Users/Documents/Projects/DataStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/Projects/DataStore/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
[8/31/19 12:40:54 AM]     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with this connection string:

`mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@vm1:10255/admin?ssl=true`

Note that `localhost` is still used as the username. `vm1` is specified as the machine name after `@`.